# All the posible ways to decode an image

Tags: java, dynamic, dynamic-programming

A top secret message containing uppercase letters from 'A' to 'Z' has been encoded as numbers using the following mapping:

'A' -> 1
'B' -> 2
...
'Z' -> 26
You are an FBI agent and you need to determine the total number of ways that the message can be decoded.

Since the answer could be very large, take it modulo 10^9 + 7.

Example

For message = "123", the output should be
mapDecoding(message) = 3.

"123" can be decoded as "ABC" (1 2 3), "LC" (12 3) or "AW" (1 23), so the total number of ways is 3.

I found these 2 solutions but I cannot understand any of them and the equation used

```
int mapDecoding(String m) {
    for (var e : m.getBytes())
        k = v / 49 * 554 / (v * 10 + e) * c + (v = e) / 49 * (c = k %= 1e9 + 7);
    return k;
}
int c, v, k = 1;
```

---

the second solution

```
int a, b = 1, c;
int mapDecoding(String m){
    for(int d : m.getBytes())
        b = 63/(c%49*9+d)*a + (c=d)/49 * (a=b%=1e9+7);
    return b;
}
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: it is modulos 10^9 + 7